# Hybrid Textarea - autogrow to fixed height, then apply scroll bar

Tags: textarea, scrollbar, autogrow

Is there a way to create a hybrid textarea with both starting height, a max height following autogrow, and then scroll bars appearing from then on?

All examples I've seen online are either autogrow or scroll bar, but nothing that encompasses both.